# Decreasing the processing time of code using parallel computing

Tags: c, parallel-processing, jobs, hpc

I am new to HPC and parallel computing and don't have much knowledge about it.
I want to run this code for different r values from 1-65 (Highlighted by CHANGE HERE comment). I am using HPC for this. I want to know if there is any way to decrease the processing time for this code. For smaller r, it is okay. But for large values of r (>8), it is taking too much time.

The script used to submit the job is also attached. I am sorry if you find this question trivial but I don't have much experience in this field. Please help!

Thanks and regards,
C

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

double z=0.0;
double c=0.0;
long count=0;

void comb(double arr[][65], int n, int r, int index, double data[][10],int i); //CHANGE HERE
double corrcoef(double avg[]);
void val_transfer(double arr[][65], int n, int r)
{       double data[16][10];                                            //CHANGE HERE

        comb(arr, n, r, 0,data,0);

}

void comb(double arr[][65], int n, int r, int index, double data[][10],int i) //CHANGE HERE
{

        double avg[16]={0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0};
        if (index == r)
                {
                double sum[16]={0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0};
                for (int k=0;k<16;k++)
                        {
                        //printf("\n");
                        for (int j=0; j<r; j++)
                                {//printf("%lf\t",data[k][j]);
                                sum[k]=sum[k]+data[k][j];
                                }
                        avg[k]=sum[k]/r;
                        //printf("\n");
                        //printf("%lf\t",avg[k]);
                        }

                corrcoef(avg);
                /*double z=z+x;
                count=count+1;
                double c=z/count;
        printf("%lf\n",c);*/
                }

        if (i>=n)
        return;
        for (int l=0; l<16;l++)
                {
                //printf("%lf\t",data[l][1]);
                data[l][index] = arr[l][i];
                //printf("%lf\t",data[l][1]);
                //printf("\n");
                }
        comb(arr,n,r,index+1,data,i+1);
        comb(arr,n,r,index,data,i+1);
}

 double corrcoef(double avg[])
{
        double x[16];
        //double y[4];
double xy[16];
double xsquare[16];
double ysquare[16];
        int i;
        //double xsum, ysum, xysum, xsqr_sum, ysqr_sum;
        double coeff;
        double num;
        double deno;
        //double z=0.0;
        //double c=0.0;
        //long count=0;

        double xsum =0;
        double ysum =0;
        double xysum =0;
        double xsqr_sum =0;
        double ysqr_sum = 0;
        int p=16;
        for (i = 0; i < p; i++)
                x[i]=avg[i];
                //printf("%lf\t%lf\t",x[i],y[i]);

        /* find the needed data to manipulate correlation coeff */
        for (i = 0; i < p; i++) {
                xy[i] = x[i] * y[i];
                xsquare[i] = x[i] * x[i];
                ysquare[i] = y[i] * y[i];
                xsum = xsum + x[i];
                ysum = ysum + y[i];
                xysum = xysum + xy[i];
                xsqr_sum = xsqr_sum + xsquare[i];
                ysqr_sum = ysqr_sum + ysquare[i];
        }

        num = 1.0 * ((p * xysum) - (xsum * ysum));
        deno = 1.0 * ((p * xsqr_sum - xsum * xsum)* (p * ysqr_sum - ysum * ysum));

        /* calculate correlation coefficient */
        coeff = num / sqrt(deno);

        /* print the result */
        //printf("Correlation Coefficient : %.4lf\t", coeff);
                z=z+coeff;
                //printf("%lf\t",z);
                count=count+1;
                c=z/count;
               //printf("%lf\n",c);
        return (coeff);
  }



int main()
 {

 FILE *fin;
 FILE *foutR1;
 fin= fopen("input_data.txt","r");
 double arr[16][65];
 int i,j;
 for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)

       {for (j=0;j<65;j++)
        {fscanf(fin, "%lf\t", &arr[i][j]);
        //printf("%lf ",arr[i][j]);}

        }
//printf("\n");
 }

//double pl;
/*double arr[4][3]={
                {5,2,3},
                {4,5,6},
                {9,8,9},
                {10,11,12},
                };*/
 int r = 10;                            //CHANGE HERE
 int n = 65;

 val_transfer(arr, n, r);
 printf("\n%lf",c);
 foutR1=fopen("ens_skill.txt","a");
 fprintf(foutR1,"%d\t%lf\n",r,c);
return 0;
}
```

LSF SCRIPT USED TO SUBMIT THE JOB

```
#!/bin/bash
#BSUB -J corr
#BSUB -n 64
#BSUB -q large
#BSUB -o mpi%J.out
#BSUB -e err%J.err


export SAVE_ALL_TASKS=no
export I_MPI_FABRICS=shm:tcp
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=2
export I_MPI_FALLBACK=0
export OMP_STACKSIZE=16000000
export KMP_AFFINITY=verbose,scatter
export FORT_BUFFERED=yes

g++ ensmem_skill_final.cc
mpiexec.hydra ./a.out
```

Comment: Fix-my-code questions are off-topic here. Recommendations: Read a good C programming book. Read some [introduction to algorithms](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/introduction-algorithms). Compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/); `g++` is for C++ code not for C code). For benchmarking add some optimization options (e.g. `-O2`). Consider installing some Linux distribution on your laptop. See also http://norvig.com/21-days.html for a useful insight

Comment: Please make sure you show an MCVE ([MCVE]).  There shouldn't be big chunks of commented out code in what you show us.  Or, more likely, you should use `//` and not `/*` to start a one-line comment.  (That's at: `corrcoef(avg);
                /*double z=z+x;`… where that comment continues through the start of a function, etc.  It would be surprising if it compiles, in fact.  Code should compile before being shown on SO, unless your problem is getting the code to compile, but that isn't supposed to be your problem.)

Comment: I am really sorry for the mistake. I have corrected it. The code compiles and runs fine for smaller values of r. What I want to know that if I use parallel processing for this code, will the processing time decrease?

The matrix data has dimensions of [16][r], which has to be changed for different values of r.

Comment: You probably are lacking knowledge that you'll need years of hard work to learn. We cannot teach all that here, sorry. I gave a few references in my first comment

Comment: *You probably are lacking knowledge that you'll need years of hard work to learn.*  Not really, I doubt that it should take anyone more than about 3 months of diligent application to the topic to learn enough to answer this question. That aside, I agree that asking this question here on SO is not the right place to start.

Comment: Thanks a lot for providing the references. I will read it. Thank for mentioning that it will take ~3 months. That's encouraging.

Comment: This is a very nice introduction to MPI (parallel computing) in C: http://www.cs.usfca.edu/~peter/ppmpi/ The first 5 chapters should be enough for regular parallelizations. There are exercise solutions on the website but it's best if you solve them yourself. Otherwise it's like others here suggested - you need to learn C.